# access denied for an empty page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have crated SharePoint Mapped Folder _layouts/myfolder in Visual Studio and I have added an allmost empty aspx page.

User1 has no rights on root site collection (http://mydomain)

I have created a Workspace with break inheritance (unique inheritance) and I have added User1 to it as Administator.

When I log in as User1 to the WorkSapces and then browse to 
http://mydomain/_layouts/myfolder/mypage.aspx
I get access denied. 
I dont want to add user1 to the root site collection.
thanks for your advice

Comment: Have you tried `http://mydomain/WORKSPACEURL/_layouts/myfolder/mypage.aspx`

Comment: Thanks, it was the problem, when i tried what you wrote it worked.

Comment: @PerJakobsen you should post your comment as an answer so Medes can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `http://mydomain/WORKSPACEURL/_layouts/myfolder/mypage.aspx`